# How to force GNOME to use Wayland?

Tags: xorg, gnome, arch-linux, gnome-shell, wayland

## TL;DR

gnome-shell does not want to be a Wayland compositor.

**Edit:** Sometimes it does want to be, sometimes it doesn't.

#### Log

```
Dec 31 06:55:26 speedy-desktop gnome-shell[393]: Can't initialize KMS backend: could not find drm kms device
Dec 31 06:55:29 speedy-desktop /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session[410]: (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
```

I have 2 video cards. (See LSPCI below)

## Extended Problem

I've been told that GNOME uses Wayland by default. But for some reason, I don't know how to get them to work together. [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wayland) just mentions the usage of weston and the [GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM) & [GNOME](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME) pages don't say anything about wayland... only the GNOME page, but that's only for manual startup.

```
⚡ loginctl show-session c6 -p Type 
Type=x11 -- GDM

⚡ loginctl show-session c7 -p Type
Type=x11 -- GNOME
```

### Tries

1. Putting `export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland` to `/etc/profile` => no result
2. Reinstalling the `gnome` group (`yaourt -S gnome`) => messed up my `NetworkManager`, but I fixed that myself.
3. Launching `weston` from an X session => works, but `weston-launch` from a tty hanged my PC... (I can't find logs, if you can comment their path, I'll post them, `journalctl -xe` doesn't seem to contain anything wayland-or-weston-related)

   The only thing I did find in `journalctl -xe -b -1` is this:

   ```
   Dec 31 07:18:08 speedy-desktop kernel: radeon_dp_aux_transfer_native: 158 callbacks suppressed
   ```
4. Put `MUTTER_ALLOW_HYBRID_GPUS=1` to `/etc/environment` => no result

### Almost working...

I was looking through the journal, and... what did I find?

```
Dec 31 04:31:57 speedy-desktop /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-wayland-session[382]: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: file too short
Dec 31 04:31:57 speedy-desktop /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-wayland-session[382]: Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
```

The file wasn't simply short, it was EMPTY. How? I have no idea.

After lots of g00gling it turned out that my pacman database was corrupt (somehow), and this one-liner (posted [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1568802#p1568802)) fixed it.

```
LANG= pacman -Qkk 2>&1 | grep "^.*: no mtree file$" | cut -d: -f1 | sudo xargs pacman -S --force --noconfirm
```

**BUT** GNOME still uses X11. I have absolutely no idea why. Here's the problem:

```
Dec 31 06:55:26 speedy-desktop gnome-shell[393]: Can't initialize KMS backend: could not find drm kms device
Dec 31 06:55:29 speedy-desktop /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session[410]: (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
```

X server knows that there is KMS, but `gnome-shell` doesn't?! What?

#### Configs?

DEFAULT. I simply haven't touched them. (Or at least I have reversed my modifications)

#### LSPCI

```
⚡ lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7560D]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E]
```

#### Any help is appreciated!

PS: Just ran `yaourt -Syu` a couple seconds ago.

Comment: have you tried manually running `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session` from console? does it also freeze your system?

Comment: One second... Just FYI, it now works... Partially. Sometimes it starts wayland, sometimes X. I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem width GDM ("Just FYI, it now works... Partially. Sometimes it starts wayland, sometimes X") and to solve my problem I had to add a driver card module to my mkinitcpio config file. Was something to do with concurrency load with systemd or something like that. Im not an expert so i really dont know.
something like this ([**i915** for intel or **nouveau** for nvidia](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting#Early_KMS_start)):

in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf

```
MODULES=(... i915 ...)
```

and then run:

```
# mkinitcpio
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion CondeGil! Even though this is an old post, and this exact solution is for Intel graphics ("`i915` for Intel graphics", "`amdgpu` for AMDGPU, or `radeon` when using the legacy ATI driver") it might help other people! (Since this I've already moved on to a GTX 1050Ti, which works flawlessly with KMS)